# Assets like css js are not working with sitecore 9.3 as expected

Tags: sitecore-client

with sitecore 8.1, @styles.Render("virtual path") and @scripts.Render("Virtual Path") are working fine. But with Sc9.3, it is stopped working, i am getting 404 error for these in network tab.

Can someone please let me know what is causing this issue.

thanks

Comment: Can you add some more details here such as log errors, implementation is based on `global.asax` or `InitializeRoutes`?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat here is log error: There is no context database OR content database in Site Specific Alias Resolver. Details: Sitecore.Web.RequestUrl
  Request is redirected to document not found page. Requested url: /assets/toolkit/forms, User: extranet\Anonymous, Website: exxxxxxxx

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat        MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
            Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.ResetCache(true);
            AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
                try
            {
               this.Container = (IKernel)new StandardKernel(new INinjectModule[0]);
                new PostNinjectSolrStartUp(this.Container).Initialize();
            }